# SELECT Excerpt?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to `SELECT` only an excerpt of an (text based as `nvarchar`, `text`, ..) column?

I'm especially asking for MySQL.

If yes: How can I do this and would it be even worth it (respectively performance)?

Why I'm asking this?
I'm building an overview about *items* which shall show only an excerpt of one field of one item. Since this text field could be up to 65535 characters I just want to get the first X characters to improve the query performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the [`LEFT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

```
SELECT LEFT(my_text_column_name, X) FROM text_table
```

The above will retrieve the first `X` characters.